# Left border does not appear in chartjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chart.js

The visibility is restricted to the upper, right, and bottom edges of the square, with the left side remaining entirely concealed. There are no discernible features on the left. I desire the inclusion of embroidery along every side of the square, thereby extending the decorative detailing around its entirety.
[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrBNv.png)]

```js
"use client";
import { useRef, useEffect, } from "react";
import { Chart } from "chart.js/auto";
import { border } from "@chakra-ui/react";

export function IndiceIniquidade() {
  const chartRef: any = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (chartRef.current) {
      if (chartRef.current.chart) {
        chartRef.current.chart.destroy();
      }

      const context = chartRef.current.getContext("2d");

      const newChart = new Chart(context, {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
          labels: [""],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Bom",
              data: [{ x: [0, 20], y: "" }],
              backgroundColor: ["rgba(219, 96, 116, 1)"],
            },
            {
              label: "Ruim",
              data: [{ x: [20, 40], y: 0 }],
              backgroundColor: ["rgba(236, 141, 84, 1)"],
              borderColor: ["rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)"],
              borderWidth:2
              
            },
            {
              label: "Loading",
              data: [{ x: [40, 60], y: "" }],
              backgroundColor: ["rgba(254, 227, 119, 1)"],
              borderColor: ["rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)"],
            },
            {
              label: "Loading2",
              data: [{ x: [60, 80], y: "" }],
              backgroundColor: ["rgba(197, 202, 108, 1)"],
              borderColor: ["rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)"],
            },
            {
              label: "Loading3",
              data: [{ x: [80, 100], y: "" }],
              backgroundColor: ["rgba(142, 171, 103, 1)"],
            },
          ],
        },
        options: {
          indexAxis: "y",
          aspectRatio: 3,
          scales: {
            y: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              stacked: true,
            },
            x: {
              display: false,
            },
            
          },
          plugins: {
            legend: {
              display: false,
            },
          },
          layout: {
            padding: 0
          },
          responsive: true,
        },
      });

      chartRef.current.chart = newChart;
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: "50px" }}>
      <canvas ref={chartRef} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the doc [by default](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#dataset-properties) the left border of horizontal bars will not be drawn. (`BorderSkipped Default='start'`)

You can show the border by adding `borderSkipped:false` for each bar you want to show the borders:

```js
datasets: [
    {
      label: "Bom",
      data: [{ x: [0, 20], y: "" }],
      backgroundColor: ["rgba(219, 96, 116, 1)"],
    },
    {
      label: "Ruim",
      data: [{ x: [20, 40], y: 0 }],
      backgroundColor: ["rgba(236, 141, 84, 1)"],
      borderColor: ["rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)"],
      borderWidth:2,
      borderSkipped: false //Add this line.
    },
    ...
]
```